# computer vision - assemble single large-scale videostream from number of cameras

Tags: video, computer-vision, video-processing, video-capture

I'm new to computer vision and looking for advice/reference to the existing works/products.

There are some software products which allow creating panorama picture form series of usual pictures. I would need kind of similar, but for video streams, not for still images.

Let's say initial video streams are transmitted from stationary fixed / mounted and not moving devices such as smartphones or cameras. Each device has fullHD stream with 30fps frame rate which gives me about 1pixel per mm of surface I need to watch for. I need some software that could take 10-20-30 of such streams and combine them into a single video where I will be able to see a picture of 4K or 8K resolution which is covering several square meters of surface. So target software is capable of glueing together pictures so there is no overlap / duplication of images.

Appreciate if you point me to any of existing things in this area.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41873071/334402

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has a stitching module.

you can estimate the transform once from images with good correspondences/matches, and then apply that transform over and over to your video frames.